# Getting The connection to localhost was interrupted. When trying to send a JSON representation of a [DataContract] marked object

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf, asp.net-4.0, datacontractserializer

I am using the following method to send a **JSON representation** of a List of a custom object through a WCF service hosted on my local machine:

```
 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<MyObject> GetObjects()
    {
        return MyObject.GetObjects();
    }
```

The class MyObject is marked with the [DataContract] attribute, When I request the method using Rest URL, I get the error

> This webpage is not available, The connection to localhost was interrupted.

When I remove the **[DataContract]** atribute, it works fine. I read many articles that you should enable SSL and configure the service behavior to set the certificate name and store and that sort of stuff, but isthis the right and only way to make it work? Shouldn't it be straighforward?

The code for MyObject is :

```
  [DataContract]
public class MyObject
{

    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get ; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Seems like you are having a serialization problem with `MyObject`. By removing the DataContract attribute you are telling WCF to use a default serialization of the object. There may be some difference in how WCF serialization behaves when you mark a class with DataContract. You'll need to post more detail about `MyObject` to get a better answer. Also try [enabling WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to see what WCF is actual getting and doing with the requests.

Comment: I added the code for MyObject, :) 10x

Comment: Your `MyObject` code isn't complete. The backing field `Id` of the `ID` property isn't defined in the class. Also, what version of the .NET framework are you using?

Comment: I am using .net Framework version version 4.0. And you are right, I forgot to copy that, Edited the question

Comment: I can't see why adding or removing the `DataContract/DataMember` attributes would make difference to WCF since the properties are value types like `int` or `string`. Also, .NET 4.0 supports inferring the contract from a class with serializable types. Seems like the issue may be in how the WCF JSON serializer behaves. Look at [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37069/JSON-serialization-and-de-serialization-in-WCF-Dat) to see how JSON serialization works in WCF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that all the properties marked as [DataMember] have get and set, that is they are not readonly, not sure why but I once faced this issus and solved it like this.

Comment: Ammazing, I really had a propery with no set, I forgot to mention it in my code snippet, thanks a lot